# To check declaration of a variable before compilation

Tags: vim, ide, compilation

I code in C/C++ and use vim for editing. I have found that most of times after completing my code when I compile, I get undeclared variables error. These are variables which I forgot to declare before using them.

I want to know is there any utility with vim which I can use for testing if all variables in new code are declared before use. It will save my considerable compile time.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The [clang-complete plugin](https://github.com/Rip-Rip/clang_complete) can do this.

Have a look at its `clang_complete-copen` and `clang_complete-periodic_quickfix` configuration variables to enable the checks.